# How to use v-for by reading json data?

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vuejs3

I want to use v-for to generate some `<li>` elements by reading json data.

this is my code,json `urls` as data.

```
<script>
    const urls =[
        {text:'math',href:'math',icon:'bi bi-calculator'},
        {text:'chemistry',href:'chemistry',icon:'bi bi-boxes'},
    ]
</script>

<template lang="ejs">
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md py-3" style="background: rgb(89,154,143);">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-2">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item" v-for="(item, index) in urls">
                        <a class="nav-link link-light" href=${item.href}><i class="${item.icon}"></i>${item.href}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>
```

but it returns

```
[eslint] 
D:\+coding\webpagetools2.0\src\components\navBar.vue
  2:11  error  'urls' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
```

It seems the `urls` json data doesn't include in template but script.How to resolve it?

I have been tried to move

```
const urls =[
        {text:'數學工具',href:'math',icon:'bi bi-calculator'},
        {text:'化學工具',href:'chemistry',icon:'bi bi-boxes'},
    ]
```

to template section ,but it doesn't work.

Comment: i had to add  :key="index" after v-for, maybe that will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to use the script setup syntax, and you're missing the `setup` attribute in the script tag :

```html
<script setup>
    const urls =[
        {text:'math',href:'math',icon:'bi bi-calculator'},
        {text:'chemistry',href:'chemistry',icon:'bi bi-boxes'},
    ]
</script>
```

it's recommended to define your variables as reactive properties using `ref` or `reactive` :

```html
<script setup>
  import {ref} from 'vue'
  
  const urls =ref([
        {text:'math',href:'math',icon:'bi bi-calculator'},
        {text:'chemistry',href:'chemistry',icon:'bi bi-boxes'},
    ])
</script>
```